# Object detection on ESP32

Tags: machine-learning

Currently I'm working on a project to perform on device object detection on a ESP32.
In combinbation with trying to perform OTA on the ESP's to make it easier to exchange models.

I'm looking for an easier way to remake models and add or remove classifier's instead of retraining and remaking them in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: What does "easier" mean for you? You don't need a Jupyter notebook. It's Python, so you can also make it a .py file and run it. The OTA update is probably as easy as you implemented it and has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for an easier way to implement models on microcontrollers. I recommend you start looking into TinyML.

Edge Impulse is also a really useful tool to quickly implement object detection on microcontrollers